# How do I create an dynamic and unique array of row values that are Changed in html table

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamic html table built with different rows where each row has 
set of particular Fields like textboxes and i have a button which updates all the changed 
rows. was able to track which row was changed where we will be getting the row number that has been changed

How do i create a dynamic array of all the row numbers that are being changed in the table 
how do i create a format for the changed row values and send to the server for update

```
        var m = 0;
        var changedrows = {};
        $.each($('input[id*=mid_],select[id*=mse_]')).live('change',function(m){
          var num= $(this).parent().html()*1; // Able to get the row  number correctly 
          alert("changed row is"+num);      
          changedrows[m] = {row:num};           
            m++;                      
         });
```

how do i create a dynamic  and unique array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `defaultValue` and `defaultSelected` properties of form fields.  First, find all the inputs whose `defaultValue` differs from its `value`:

```
var changedFields = $("input[id*=mid]").filter(function () {
    return this.defaultValue != this.value;
});
```

Then, find all the list boxes whose `defaultSelected` differs from the current selection:

```
changedFields.add($("select[id*=mse_]").filter(function () {
    return !this.options[this.selectedIndex].defaultSelected;
}));
```

Note, that if no `<option>` has a `selected` attribute, all of the options will have `defaultSelected` as false.  One way you could address that would be to find the default option.  The default option would be the last option that has `defaultSelected` as true, and if none do, then the default option would be the first option.

```
changedFields.add($("select[id*=mse_]").filter(function () {
    var defaultOption = $("option", this).filter(function () {
        return this.defaultSelected;
    });
    defaultOption = defaultOption.length ? defaultOption.last()[0] : this.options[0];
    return this.options[this.selectedIndex] != defaultOption;
}));
```

Then, find their parent rows:

```
var changedRows = changedFields.closest("tr");
```

Then, get an array of row indexes from the rows using `.map()`:

```
var changedRowIndexes = changedRows.map(function () {
    return $(this).index();
}).get();
```

Now, `changedRowIndexes` is an array of numbers indicating the index of each row with an input element that has changed.

After you've sent the changes to the server, it may be a good idea to update the `defaultValue` of your inputs:

```
changedFields.filter("input").each(function () {
    this.defaultValue = this.value;
});
changedFields.filter("select").each(function () {
    $("option", this).each(function () {
        this.defaultSelected = false;
    });
    this.options[this.selectedIndex].defaultSelected = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try something along the lines of the following (untested) code:

```
var changedrows = []; // Use an array

$('#yourtableid').on('change', 'input[id*=mid_],select[id*=mse_]', function() {
    var num = $(this).closest('tr').index();
    if(changedrows.indexOf(num) == -1) {
        changedrows.push(num);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have an array of all the changed rows.

Now, when you want to submit the forms, loop through your array and use [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) to convert each changed row into a query string.

Each query string will start with the "?" character, so you'll need to use substring() to deal with that.

You can then use [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) to submit the data to the server.